# read-char-by-name to start from Arrows or Dingbats

Tags: characters, utf-8

Using `(read-char-by-name "utfname: ")` how can I start from `Arrows` or `Dingbats` rather than painfully starting from "Null" "START OF HEADING", ...

Comment: How many times do you need to be told to read the doc string of the function? `C-h f read-char-by-name` says: `You can type a few of the first letters of the Unicode name and
use completion.  If you type a substring of the Unicode name
preceded by an asterisk ‘*’ and use completion, it will show all
the characters whose names include that substring, not necessarily
at the beginning of the name.
`

Comment: Yes, but I do not know what keys should be used for showing possible completions for the phrase.

Comment: Usually when using commands I can complete with `TAB` (e.g. `M-x read-char-TAB`).  But this does not help when doing `*ARROW*TAB`, `*ARROWTAB`.

Comment: I still need an explanation on how completion words for `read-char-by-name`.

Comment: Really? `*ARROW<TAB>` gives me a completion buffer with rouglhy 700 completions. I then continue with `H<TAB>`, it completes to `*ARROWHEAD`, I then type another `<TAB>` and I get 82 completions. At that point, everything fits into one windowful, so I click on something to select it. I don't know how `read-char-by-name` does its completion, but it seems to work fine for me.

Comment: If I do `BLACK<TAB>`, completion happens.  But with `*BLACK<TAB>`, no matches get listed.

Comment: The first one gives me 198 completions. The second one gives me 389 completions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139703/discussion-between-nickd-and-konmi).